# jQuery Initial Function Call Not Working

Tags: jquery

I am updating divisions through an Ajax call that has a set interval; which works and updates correctly including when it is accessed from another click event, except for the standalone first call made before the interval is set.

The call (does not update):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var c = 0;
$(".content").load('coreprocessing.php',function(){
    $(".content").fadeIn(400,function(){
        refreshIt();
    });
});
```

with refresh set:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(refreshIt,60000);
```

immediately following the load call.

Function:

```
function refreshIt(){
    var page = $(".navselected").attr('id');
    var ids = $('.content div[id]').map(function(){
        return this.id;
    }).get();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:page + 'functions.php',
        data:{'idList[]':ids},
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            $.each(data,function(element,load){
                var elem = $("#" + element);
                elem.slideUp(400,function(){
                    elem.removeClass("critical ok").addClass(load.status).html(load.number).slideDown(400);
                    if(load.status == 'critical'){ c++;}
                });
            });
        updateInfoBar(c);
        if(page == 'coreprocessing'){ updatePumpDataBar() }
        c = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

When I "alert(c)", it pops up when load.status is critical (as intended), however it insists on returning 0 the first time. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I have played around with scope but can't seem to figure this one out.

-Justin

Comment: You should edit and put all the code text in a code block for better understanding.

Comment: I took care of the formatting for you. It's pretty easy. Just highlight the section of code you want formatted, and click the "Code Sample" button above the question area. It looks like **`{ }`**.

Comment: Thanks for editing the code for me patrick dw. The last two questions were formatted by someone else and I hadn't realized that. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Perhaps i am not understanding your issue - but isn't 0 what you want for the first go ahead? Maybe put the updateInfoBar(c) etc.. in an oncomplete callback since "success" will fire first.. that will then set c, ala c++. If I am not understanding your question correctly, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is `c` being undefined in scope. You would need to move c out of the document ready function. I believe this is why it does not work only the first time. `c` is undefined until set at the end of the `refreshIt` function `c = 0;` (thereafter it is defined).

Comment: Hey Josiah, thanks for the suggestion but it does not remedy the problem. If i remove the declaration inside of the call it continues to increment through page refreshes, and if I remove the outer scope declaration it altogether doesn't refresh/work.